# SMD antenna connection to an RF module

Tags: rf, antenna

I want to design my first wireless device.

I want to use an RF module called [RC-S2LP-868](https://www.radiocontrolli.com/en/component/108/rc-s2lp-868).

My problem is that I don't know how to connect an SMD antenna ([ANT-868-HESM](https://linxtechnologies.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/ant-868-hesm-ds.pdf)) to that. There is a small SMA connector on the module, I think this will cause some unwanted reflections if I don't use it, right? I want to solder the antenna pin and route a 50ohm micro strip line from there to the antenna.

What should to I do?

Comment: You could start by linking data sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to eke out the very best range possible I wouldn’t worry too much about it, effectively you have a bonus 1mm antenna- how much is that likely to radiate or receive?  Removing the connector itself using a hot air rework pencil would be an option and trim back any excess Pcb track using a scalpel, and perhaps see if you can tell the difference.